# Making a 3D map with shapefiles, lidar and aerial image data

Tags: shapefile, javascript, cartography, 3d, lidar

I want to try to make a simple 3D map for a small area (10 square miles) with some housing, some roads and some vegetation on it. My geodata is as follows:

- shapes with houses/roads/vegetation.
- LIDAR point cloud data over the area (can easily be built to a dem).
- georeferenced aerial image.

Any idea where to start to bundle these geodata together and make a neat looking 3D map?

Answer (score 1):

An idea is:

1. Use the lidar data to classify ground and non-ground points. Then, build a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) from the ground points. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101786/how-to-determine-bare-earth-from-unclassified-las-file/108342#108342) is a way of doing it.
2. Use the RGB values from the aerial images to color code the lidar point cloud. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138611/assigning-rgb-values-from-geotiff-image-to-lidar-data-using-r/140201#140201) are examples showing how this can be done.

Now, it is possible to display the DEM and the color-coded point cloud in some 3D point cloud viewer (for example, take a look at [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77427/viewing-lidar-data-from-web-browser/94443#94443)).

3. The shapefiles and their attribute tables could be used to provide interactive information in the graphical user interface. But this is just one idea; not sure how to implement this part.